# Cómo actualizar un parámetro múltiples veces al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Cómo se puede actualizar un parámetro en diferentes celdas al mismo tiempo? Es decir:

Tengo una tabla donde hay varios usuarios. Cada uno de ellos tiene una columna llamada set_noved y necesito, después de ejecutar un comando, poner a 0 una columna en todos esos usuarios.

BD:

```
id |  usuario  | set_noved | placa | ruta | jornada |
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Andres    | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | Maria     | 1         | TTY651|  L   |  B      |
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | Claudia   | 1         | TTY651|  L   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | Juan      | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

PHP:

```
$placa = $_POST[ "placa" ];
$ruta = $_POST[ "r_ruta" ];
$jornada = $_POST[ "jornada" ];
$set_nov = $_POST["set_nov"];

$query2 = "UPDATE
                 escolar_users_settings
           SET
                 set_noved='$set_nov'
           WHERE
                 placa='$placa'
                 AND ruta='$ruta'
                 AND jornada='$jornada'";
mysqli_query( $connect, $query2 )or die( mysqli_error( $connect ) );
mysqli_close( $connect );
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema esta en el `where` de tu consulta. Estas filtrando por muchas cosas y cada una la tiene diferente. SI lo que quieres es cambiar a todos por el numero de placa, quita las demás.

Comment: pese a que te habia dado una respuesta correcta que debí borrar, te comento que tu mejor opción será en el where usar el operador IN para indicar solamente que va desde el id 1 hasta el id 2 entonces hará el cambio; si solo quieres hacer ese cambio los demás parametros estan de mas salvo que lo indiques en tu pregunta

Comment: ¿Que trae el campo "set_noved" ? ¿Es un arreglo?

Comment: Deberías filtrar por ID, es decir "WHERE id IN (1,2,3)"

Comment: Lo que tienes puesto es "correcto" siempre que los datos que recibas estén bien. No tienes que poner un IN por id si lo que quieres es actualizar por los campos que envías ya que el id 2 tiene tres resultados, pero con los parámetros que recibes podrías actualizar solo uno si quisieses. Cuál es tu problema? obtienes algún error o algo? Mírate este enlace: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: En primer punto te invitaria a utilizar sentencias preparadas para realizar cambios en tu BD y en segunda ¿Cual es el problema con tu query?

Comment: Tú dices lo siguiente: *y necesito, después de ejecutar un comando, poner a 0 una columna en todos esos usuarios.*  ... pero resulta que nunca explicas cómo son identificados **todos esos usuarios** de los que hablas. Con respecto a la seguridad, también te recomendaría el uso de consultas preparadas. Explica mejor tu pregunta por favor y se te podrá ayudar de la forma más adecuada y segura.